# In Excel, how can I write loop that will keep deleting the contents of a cell unless a condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So, I have three very large columns of data. I want these to match, but there are lots of mismatching rows between the columns.

What I want to do is write a looping macro to delete the contents in cell `F2` if they are not equal to the contents in either `A2` or `K2`. However, I can only find details on writing looping macros for ranges. Is it possible to have a command carried out on the same cell over and over? So far I have:

```
Sub ArrayMatch()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim F As Range
For Each F In Range("F2:F2043").Cells
 F.Select
 If ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-5]) And ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.Offset([0],        [5]) Then
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp      
  Else: Stop
  End If
  Next
```

At the moment, I just want the code to stop if any of these are equal. However, the way I have the range defined here, the code is only applied to every other cell in the range. Can I rephrase this range to have the rest of the code applied to cell `F2` over and over again?

Thanks! I'll keep experimenting with what I have while eagerly awaiting a response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input:

> Can I rephrase this range to have the rest of the code applied to cell
>   F2 over and over again?

that's NOT exactly what you expect. The clue is you should check every cell in range, and move to the NEXT only in case it does NOT meet the criteria. Otherwise the row is deleted, and you should stay on the same spot, i.e. DON'T move down, since if `A1` is removed, `A2` now becomes `A1`, and you should check it again.

The below code will do the job (perhaps you should modify the criteria, but the idea is that):

```
Sub RemoveRows()

Dim i As Long
Dim ActiveCell As Range

i = 2

Do While i <= 2043
    Set ActiveCell = Range("F" & i)
    If ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.Offset([0], [-5]) And ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.Offset([0], [5]) Then
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

This is the sample for quite similar task: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp2cwphhhdn3l98/RemoweRows210.xlsm

Comment: Great, this looks good! Would I still be able to define i as an integer these have alphanumeric numbers like BC000034, BC234445, NM0006234 etc?

Comment: @user1996971 i is a current row number for loop. It may be integer (more exactly - Long, as in code) - by definition))) Or what is your question?

Comment: No, just that the value inside the cell is alphanumerical. I found that this doesn't matter too much though. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, another question: Can you tell me the meaning of 

    Else i = i +1 

Would it be possible to write in a line to tell the code to move the selection down a column if a certain condition is met? Like

> If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset([1],[-1]) Then

Comment: @user1996971 this works as follows: if your criteria is met - you delete the row, but do NOT move down, since the row below now became current (the same i) and should be checked. `i = i + 1` i.e. move DOWN the next row is applied in case we do NOT delete the current row. If you got the idea - the solution may be different (I mean code), select anything you like / understand better. `Do...While` is the most clear and simple for me)

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
Sub checkF()

RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F2").EntireColumn)

While RowCount >= 1

If Range("F2").Value = Range("A2").Value Or Range("F2").Value = Range("K2").Value Then

    Stop

Else

    Range("F2").Delete Shift:=xlUp


End If

RowCount = RowCount - 1

Wend

End Sub
```

This will loop through the until there is 1 value left in column F and will stop when any of the values match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop that will do the following:

1. Retrieve all cell values for `row 2` of columns `A, F and K`
2. Check if the value in `F2` equals `A2` or `K2`

   - If equal, do nothing and exit macro
   - If not equal, delete the value in `F2`, shift the cells up, retrieve new `F2` value, then start over from `step 1`

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub MatchFirstRow()
Dim fCellValue As String
Dim aCellValue As String
Dim kCellValue As String
Dim shouldCheckAgain As Boolean

'get values of each cell in question
fCellValue = Cells(2, 6).Value
aCellValue = Cells(2, 1).Value
kCellValue = Cells(2, 11).Value
shouldCheckAgain = True

'loop through while the cell in "F" has a value AND the previous value wasn't a match
While Not IsEmpty(fCellValue) And Not fCellValue = "" And shouldCheckAgain
    shouldCheckAgain = False
    'If row values don't match, delete cell in F, shift up, then
    'reinitialize the F cell value for next pass
    If Not StrComp(fCellValue, aCellValue, vbTextCompare) _
        And Not StrComp(fCellValue, kCellValue, vbTextCompare) Then
        Cells(2, 6).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        fCellValue = Cells(2, 6).Value
        shouldCheckAgain = True
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Simply paste this code into the VB Editor for the sheet that contains the columns in question. For example, if `Sheet1` has the columns, then open the Visual Basic Editor, double click `Sheet1`, then paste the code there.

Once the code is pasted you can run this as a regular macro by choosing the `Macros` button.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this **without** loops, either with

1. Inserting a working column that uses an `=OR(F2=K2,F2=A2)` to return `True` or `False` results, then use `AutoFilter` either manually or with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to delete the False results
2. Get funky and do (1) directly in a variant array like below, then dump the variant array back over the original range

**code**

```
Sub GetEm()
X = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(--(F2:F2043=A2:A2043)+--(F2:F2043=K2:K2043),F2:F2043,""x"")")), "x", False)
Range("F2:F2043").Value = vbNullString
[f2].Resize(UBound(X), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet_Change` sub of the sheet should work here. That sub gets called whenever a cell in that sheet changes.

```
'This sub placed in one of the "Sheet1"/"Sheet2"/... objects in the list of
'Microsoft Excel Object in the VBA Editor will be called everytime you change
'a cell value in the corresponding sheet.
'"Target" is the effected cell.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check that Target is cell F2 (6th column, 2nd row)
    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 6 Then
        'If this is the cell we are looking for call the sub ValidateF2
        ValidateF2
    End If
End Sub
```

And:

```
Sub ValidateF2()
    'Check that the value of F2 is not equal to A2 or K2
    If Not (Range("F2").Value = Range("A2").Value Or Range("K2").Value = Range("K2").Value) Then
        'Set the value of F2 to "" (empty)
        Range("F2").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't fully understand how this code works though. Would you mind elaborating a bit? What is the relevance of the line

    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 6 Then

Also, what effect will having Range("f2").Value = "" have on the cell? 

Thanks again!

Comment: See my edit. Although I have to admit that (reading your question again) I am not so sure anymore that this is really what you wanted...

Comment: @hsan i think the OP wants a one and done type macro, not an event driven validator.