# Optimizing recorded macro; I know I need to write a loop, but am unsure how to do so

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a block of code that goes like this:

```
Range("C3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("S3:BL3").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Range("C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("S4:BL4").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

... and so on until row 257
```

The only part of the code that changes are the ranges I am selecting, so I know that I can write a loop to accomplish this without having to repeat myself on all of the other code, but I'm not really sure where to begin.

I want to do some counter like this, but I know I can't just put the variable "x" next to the column letter to have it repeat the process:

```
 For x = 3 to 256
    Range("Cx").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Sx:BLx").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I have found examples of loops in VBA code on Stack Overflow. I have not found examples of loops in VBA code on Stack Overflow which involve selecting a range, copying that range, selecting a new range, filtering on that range, and then pasting special over that new range.

With the ranges being the variables, it appears to be a different dynamic than a simple loop example.

Comment: lol the likelihood of finding an example that fits your needs 100% is next to nil. pnuts was suggesting that you study some similar examples and apply them. You know, not asking to be spoon fed XD Hint: don't use range. Use `cells()`.

Comment: Quite funny. I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14816374/62576) in the third item in the list of related questions to the right (over there ----->>>>>>) in about half a second, and it shows how to do **exactly** what you're asking here.. It doesn't seem like you tried very hard to find an answer before posting.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you conundrum about "I can't just put x", sure you can, with concatenation. `Range("C" & x)` would provide what you're looking for.

But, based on your given example, you seem to know the range you're wanting to iterate through; why not just select the range once, and paste the range once?

```
Range("C3:C256").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("S3:BL256").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try the concatenate menthod.The problem lies in that I am selecting only cells which have numbers in them in the range `S3:B256` (i.e. I select the entire range, and then use the 'Go-to special' function). From there, I paste special-add the data. Since the ranges are not the same size, I get the paste error.

Comment: Concatenation with the longer range seems to be an issue. It won't accept `Range("S" & x : "B" & x`

Comment: Concatenation on the longer range works just fine, it's a typo in your implementation of it. Look at what you have written, and think of how it translates to a static range like I typed in: `Range("A1:B1")`

Comment: In response to your first comment, I was able to copy my example directly out and run it with no problems. If you could perhaps provide sample data in your question, I could recreate your problem.